# Machine Learning : Resumes/Profile Input , Classification of applicants

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

My data set consists of profiles/resumes of people, with various attributes, e.g. Current job,income,past companies, college etc.Using this data, I'm trying to classify the applicants into 3 categories : Good , moderate, rejected .

I have a training data set with labelled samples.

What Machine Learning algorithm should I use?

Comment: Are you willing to provide training data for the categories? It's going to be very hard to do this unsupervised, and your clustering may well reflect some dimension beyond what you actually want to cluster on.

Comment: I have training data available but I can't provide it to you. I just want some suggestions as to how should I proceed with my project. I'm doing it in python and I will use scikit-learn library.

Comment: Sorry---I didn't mean to provide to me, I meant provide to any learning algorithm. This makes it a supervised problem (which is good), and you can through any classifier you like at it. If you have scikit try Logistic Regression or an SVM.

Comment: Do you have training samples, so categorized CVs to one of the categories? If so how many and how many unlabelled? If not do you have some rules in mind of what makes a good candidate? Please give an example of the rules.